# Calling 'FaceNormalsHelper' results in 'TypeError: this.update is not a function'

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to call `FaceNormalsHelper` from the file
`three.js/src/extras/helpers/FaceNormalsHelper.js` but it seems to result in an error:

```
TypeError: this.update is not a function
this.update();
```

The error occurs at line 32 in the mentioned file.
This is how I do the calling (look at the last line):

```
    var mesher = function mesher ( aGeometry, position, color, name, woodTexture, debug ) {
        var texture,
            material,
            mesh;

        if (woodTexture) {
            texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'crate.gif' );
            texture.anisotropy = makeRenderer.renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
            material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } );
        } else {
            material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: color, wireframe: true, side: THREE.DoubleSide } );
        }
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh(aGeometry, material);
        if (debug) {
            var normals = THREE.FaceNormalsHelper( mesh );
            console.log("normals: ", normals);
        }
        mesh.position.set = position;
        mesh.name = name;
        mesh.callback = function() { makeDOMelements.info.innerHTML = name; };
        makeScene.scene.add( mesh );

    };
    Object.freeze(mesher);
    return mesher;
}

mesher( myBox3, new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ), 0x3bf5de, "my test Box3", true, true );
```

Comment: I don't see clearly in the code where that helper is supposed to get an "update" method from. Do you have any evidence that anybody's actually using that class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot `new`:

```
var normals = new THREE.FaceNormalsHelper( mesh );
```